# How to include the CSV file directly within the .jmx test plan file not local folder

Tags: parameters, jmeter, performance-testing, load-testing, jmeter-plugins

In my JMeter test plan, I'm currently using a CSV Data Config element to access request body values from a CSV file located on my local desktop. However, I have a requirement where I want to include the CSV file directly within the .jmx test plan file. This way, when I share the .jmx file with others, the CSV file should be included and accessible within the test plan.

I attempted to add the CSV file to the 'bin' folder, but I'm uncertain whether sharing the .jmx file alone will ensure that the CSV file is available to new users or in different locations. Is there a more reliable way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

It won't work this way, [CSV Data Set Config](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#CSV_Data_Set_Config) only contains the path to the CSV file, full or relative.

If you want to include the content of the CSV file into JMeter .jmx script you can:

1. Add [setUp Thread Group](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/thread-group-jmeter) to your test plan
2. Add [JSR223 Sampler](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_Sampler) to the setUp Thread Group
3. Put the following code into "Script" area:

   ```
   new File('test.csv').text = """column-name1,column-name-2 
   row-1-cell-1,row-1-cell-2
   row-2-cell-1,row-2-cell-2
   etc.
   """
   ```
4. It will create `test.csv` file in the current folder of JMeter in the runtime and you will be able to reference it as `test.csv` where required